# Lightning Design System - alignment utilities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am currently going through the LDS documentation and I stumbled upon the section of [alignment](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/alignment/) utilities, which contains only one example - absolute center:

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">This content will be positioned in the absolute center of its container</div>
```

Is this the only class available for alignment in the LDS, or is there some other part of documentation which lists out the remaining classes used for alignment? It looks a little bit cheesy to me, because there is only one class in the alignment section.

Answer (score 0):

LDS does not have many alignment utility classes. Other than the one you pointed out for absolute positioning. If you are using a [grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/), there are additional classes to bump/align your elements but nothing else (at least that I know of)